# how navigate screen in main page on flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-android

i want wait 5 seconds on main page and display loading animation then navigate to another page.
here is my code

```
import 'mainPage.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_spinkit/flutter_spinkit.dart';
import 'dart:async';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  bool isLoading = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    loadData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.cyan,
        body: Builder(
          builder: (context) => Center(
            child: Container(
              child: SpinKitCubeGrid(color: Colors.white, size: 50.0),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future loadData() async {
    return new Timer(Duration(seconds: 5), () {
      setState(() {
        Navigator.of(context)
            .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MainPage()));
      });
    });
  }
}
```

but i got this error:

Unhandled Exception: Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator.

what should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap `MyApp` with `MaterialApp` which will provide the right `context` to `Navigator`

```
void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyApp()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help U

```
static Route route() {
 return MaterialPageRoute<void>(builder: (_) => MyApp());
}

 onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).push<void>(MainPage.route()),
................

 static Route route() {
return MaterialPageRoute<void>(builder: (_) => MainPage());
  }

  onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).push<void>(MyApp.route()),
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try it like this? I didn't run the code but showing the basic idea. Just pass the context and call it from build function.

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  bool isLoading = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    loadData(context);

    return MaterialApp(
      ...
    );
  }

  Future loadData(context) async {
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a `context` to navigate with the `Navigator`.

To navigate without using `context` you can use a package called [GetX](https://pub.dev/packages/get#route-management)

Example:

1. Add "Get" before your MaterialApp, turning it into GetMaterialApp

   ```
    GetMaterialApp( // Before: MaterialApp(
      home: MyHome(),
    )
   ```
2. Navigate to a new screen:

   ```
    Get.to(NextScreen());
   ```